# Scrolling issue in JavaFX ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, scroll, javafx-2

I'm developing desktop application using **JavaFX**.
I have a **ListView** with a custom **CellFactory**. Each cell contains multiple nodes: Button, TextFlow, Image etc.
So here's a problem: when I am trying to scroll using mouse wheel - everything works smoothly. But when I scroll using laptop's **touchpad** I experience major lags if mouse cursor is on the cell (Everything is smooth if mouse cursor is out of the cell).

Could you please tell me how to make everything work smooth for all the cases? I considered setDisable and mouseTransparent, but they didn't suit me because I have buttons in the cells.

Comment: you mean the scroller on the touchpad?

Comment: @Elltz Im using mac. Here we can scroll by putting 2 fingers on the touchpad. Haven't tested it on over laptops' touchpads.

Comment: Does it only happen with the cursor over the cell? Do you have any logic or CSS rules regarding this condition? 
Can you post a [mcve]?